# Issue in Async wcf proxy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client

I have created async proxy for my wcf application, calling the method first time

`ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient(); 
 serviceClient.GetDataAsync(5);`

doesnt invoke the service.

I need to use SetNextstatement in IDE, second time to make this works.

Pls help me to find the root cause of this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Async invokation doesn't guarantee immediate start of invokation. It starts the process of invokation somewhere in another thread. The actual service call happens after some time (after preparations are finished), in your case it happens somewhere it between stepping to next statement.

Comment: Technically it doesn't use another thread for async IO. The Windows kernel doesn't need a thread for IO.

Comment: @usr async WCF call is not pure IO, WCF does some preparations for call (e.g. serialize parameters) and only after that actual IO happens.

Comment: @usr do you have any proofs? Anyway it doesn't really matter, what matters is that async means that actual time of call is not guaranteed.